# Sending numbers between two computers using Python

Tags: python, networking

I want to send numbers from my PC to the raspberry Pi. I tried using PyDriver to upload the number as a text file but i have problems downloading the file on the Pi. Is there a simpler method which will enable me to send numbers directly between the two. Thanks

I am having problems with downloading and authenticating the file. That is the reason I am looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: How about running a web server on your raspberry Pi that will have a simple API  to POST your file or even an HTML upload form?

Comment: Have you tried using [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) ? You may want to create a server on pi, with your PC being a client.